# Is it possible to disable "Stack too deep" errors while in development?

Tags: solidity, experimental-features, stack

I know about the [Stack too deep](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7325/stack-too-deep-try-removing-local-variables) error and the workarounds for it, but I was wondering whether it's possible to disable it while in development.

Is there a `pragma experimental` flag for this, similar to how there is one for "ABIEncoderV2"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The stack is part of the EVM specification and you can't change it.

Hope it helps.