# Why do public and external functions emit strings differently in event logs?

Tags: solidity, events

## Producing the logs

When the same event is logged with the same string argument, the `data` in the transaction receipt is different, depending on whether the function was `external` or `public`.

```
pragma solidity 0.4.19;

contract EmitStringPublicAndExternal {
    event EmitString(string logme);

    function logPublic(string logme) public {
        EmitString(logme);
    }
    
    function logExternal(string logme) external {
        EmitString(logme);
    }
}
```

When I call both functions with "glitch" (in `geth --dev`), I get logs with two different data:

- `public`: `0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006676c697463680000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`
- `external`: `0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006676c69746368`

*Note: "glitch" encoded with UTF-8, and then hex-encoded, is: `0x676c69746368`*

Why is this happening?

#### Full `public` transaction & result

```
> web3.eth.getTransaction('0xfd726f1a6f94f4050aff1baee4aa50c56d127a633bfc01ebe3b023ea926aad0f')
{
  blockHash: "0xf0e7c13f811d06874a0191da3b135649cac4c9cd42a331c611734593d441a4f3",
  blockNumber: 21,
  from: "0x39708c52aea50be256bccd350d043ff36ffbb0e6",
  gas: 124415,
  gasPrice: 1,
  hash: "0xfd726f1a6f94f4050aff1baee4aa50c56d127a633bfc01ebe3b023ea926aad0f",
  input: "0x6a85450600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006676c697463680000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  nonce: 20,
  r: "0xb13ed94a954ce5e9b0c7823f4da21561f1d2d1b1a04b44cfd1f8b65acee8e1b9",
  s: "0x1bb866cde428d538ba7920e58d64a6acb14d918a39dd8e7fb39b019dc9424261",
  to: "0x2e64f811ab15803d34e2e6c503263f1393677aa9",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  v: "0xa96",
  value: 0
}

> web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt('0xfd726f1a6f94f4050aff1baee4aa50c56d127a633bfc01ebe3b023ea926aad0f')
{
  blockHash: "0xf0e7c13f811d06874a0191da3b135649cac4c9cd42a331c611734593d441a4f3",
  blockNumber: 21,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 24415,
  from: "0x39708c52aea50be256bccd350d043ff36ffbb0e6",
  gasUsed: 24415,
  logs: [{
      address: "0x2e64f811ab15803d34e2e6c503263f1393677aa9",
      blockHash: "0xf0e7c13f811d06874a0191da3b135649cac4c9cd42a331c611734593d441a4f3",
      blockNumber: 21,
      data: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006676c697463680000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      logIndex: 0,
      removed: false,
      topics: ["0xd98695e9e68b6580b8d80f03676b8575f4cc4225687169877f72d5c2b39ff61c"],
      transactionHash: "0xfd726f1a6f94f4050aff1baee4aa50c56d127a633bfc01ebe3b023ea926aad0f",
      transactionIndex: 0
  }],
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000040000000",
  status: "0x1",
  to: "0x2e64f811ab15803d34e2e6c503263f1393677aa9",
  transactionHash: "0xfd726f1a6f94f4050aff1baee4aa50c56d127a633bfc01ebe3b023ea926aad0f",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
```

#### Full `external` transaction & result

```
> web3.eth.getTransaction('0x09677264874077078d4b271f85ec7a940cf69f9b751b9a94e1cbf0f40dff1e86')
{
  blockHash: "0xe2e6036b11aa7abe948c5008e72758186a83d679c7a3d03f55a9ad959ce12680",
  blockNumber: 22,
  from: "0x39708c52aea50be256bccd350d043ff36ffbb0e6",
  gas: 123833,
  gasPrice: 1,
  hash: "0x09677264874077078d4b271f85ec7a940cf69f9b751b9a94e1cbf0f40dff1e86",
  input: "0xd486916900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006676c697463680000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  nonce: 21,
  r: "0xe06e321ae4e3031ba30a32585050d5ed10388bba591e33d5e3d17077e2dd7323",
  s: "0x7b2d1a18453ef5bd66d8065fbf1f159d029b3a64b52488382cfb8bafc6b00f09",
  to: "0x2e64f811ab15803d34e2e6c503263f1393677aa9",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  v: "0xa96",
  value: 0
}

> web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt('0x09677264874077078d4b271f85ec7a940cf69f9b751b9a94e1cbf0f40dff1e86')
{
  blockHash: "0xe2e6036b11aa7abe948c5008e72758186a83d679c7a3d03f55a9ad959ce12680",
  blockNumber: 22,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 23833,
  from: "0x39708c52aea50be256bccd350d043ff36ffbb0e6",
  gasUsed: 23833,
  logs: [{
      address: "0x2e64f811ab15803d34e2e6c503263f1393677aa9",
      blockHash: "0xe2e6036b11aa7abe948c5008e72758186a83d679c7a3d03f55a9ad959ce12680",
      blockNumber: 22,
      data: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006676c69746368",
      logIndex: 0,
      removed: false,
      topics: ["0xd98695e9e68b6580b8d80f03676b8575f4cc4225687169877f72d5c2b39ff61c"],
      transactionHash: "0x09677264874077078d4b271f85ec7a940cf69f9b751b9a94e1cbf0f40dff1e86",
      transactionIndex: 0
  }],
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000040000000",
  status: "0x1",
  to: "0x2e64f811ab15803d34e2e6c503263f1393677aa9",
  transactionHash: "0x09677264874077078d4b271f85ec7a940cf69f9b751b9a94e1cbf0f40dff1e86",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
```

#### `web3.js` parses both formats

```
> espe.allEvents({'fromBlock': 0, toBlock: 'latest'}).get()
[{
    address: "0x2e64f811ab15803d34e2e6c503263f1393677aa9",
    args: {
      logme: "glitch"
    },
    blockHash: "0xf0e7c13f811d06874a0191da3b135649cac4c9cd42a331c611734593d441a4f3",
    blockNumber: 21,
    event: "EmitString",
    logIndex: 0,
    removed: false,
    transactionHash: "0xfd726f1a6f94f4050aff1baee4aa50c56d127a633bfc01ebe3b023ea926aad0f",
    transactionIndex: 0
}, {
    address: "0x2e64f811ab15803d34e2e6c503263f1393677aa9",
    args: {
      logme: "glitch"
    },
    blockHash: "0xe2e6036b11aa7abe948c5008e72758186a83d679c7a3d03f55a9ad959ce12680",
    blockNumber: 22,
    event: "EmitString",
    logIndex: 0,
    removed: false,
    transactionHash: "0x09677264874077078d4b271f85ec7a940cf69f9b751b9a94e1cbf0f40dff1e86",
    transactionIndex: 0
}]
```

## The `external` version appears to produce an invalid ABI encoding

As I read [this section of the ABI doc](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI#formal-specification-of-the-encoding) (emphasis mine), the version of the event without the trailing 0s seems broken:

> `bytes`, of length k (which is assumed to be of type `uint256`):
>
> enc(X) = enc(k) pad_right(X), i.e. the number of bytes is encoded as a uint256 followed by the actual value of X as a byte sequence, **followed by the minimum number of zero-bytes such that `len(enc(X))` is a multiple of 32**.

## Why am I asking?

I don't think this affects the question, but just in case...

The `eth-abi` python utility rejects the `external` version of the event log as invalid. I'm trying to make sure I understand if the ABI spec and `eth-abi` need to be updated, or ... is this a Solidity bug?

Comment: FYI, I can reproduce this in the JavaScript VM in Remix. I do believe this is likely a Solidity bug. Please make sure you report it.

Comment: Ok, just posted the issue in https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/3493

Comment: I dont think so that is bug, because of memory management 
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19380/external-vs-public-best-practices?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @carver hope you understand concept, please mark as accepted. It will help community to find ans easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Solidity team confirmed that external function event logging has a bug: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/3493

> `public` should be the correct one :)

The fix is scheduled to be released in v0.5.0

Answer (score 3):

Nice catch. Its not bug, your getting different results because of public and external functions will handle memory differently.

In solidity public function immediately copies array arguments to memory. While copying to memory EVM will do 32 bytes padding.

```
EmitString(logme)
```

> 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006676c69746368

As per EVM documentation `EmitString(logme)` **logme** is string type saving or representation would be 1st 32 bytes(32*2=64 chars) will represents location of string

> 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020 = 32

Now pointer will move to 33bytes to next 32 bytes is length so length is

> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006 = 6, i.e next 6 bytes are data.
>
> 676c69746368 hex representation of string.

Memory representation of any bytes is padded with multiples of  32 bytes. Thats a reason you are getting `676c697463680000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Where is case of external functions can read directly from calldata. What is values your passing it will send same thing to the network. So thats reason you able to see only `676c69746368`

Memory allocation is expensive, whereas reading from calldata is cheap.

**That means its not a bug.**

[`external` vs `public` best practices](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19380/external-vs-public-best-practices?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: @carver hope you understand concept, please mark as accepted. It will help community to find ans easily.