# What is calldata?

Tags: contract-invocation, abi, calldata

What is calldata? I learned that there are three types of memories:

1. Storage
2. Memory
3. Stack

In the Ethereum docs, it says that the function parameters are of type memory by default.

However, I've also read an article which said that function arguments are stored in calldata.

Now, I don't know what calldata is, can somebody please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: in simpler term calldata is the data provided within the call made to the smart contract. as @eth have explained it's the function's signature and the parameters provided.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here is an example from [What is an ABI and why is it needed to interact with contracts?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/234/what-is-an-abi-and-why-is-it-needed-to-interact-with-contracts)

```
contract Foo {
  function baz(uint32 x, bool y) returns (bool r) { r = x > 32 || y; }
}
```

If we wanted to call `baz()` with the parameters `69` and `true`, we would pass 68 bytes in total, which can be broken down into:

> 0xcdcd77c0: the Method ID. This is derived as the first 4 bytes of the
> Keccak-256 hash of the ASCII form of the signature baz(uint32,bool).
> 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000045:
> the first parameter, a uint32 value 69 padded to 32 bytes. (69 is hex 0x45.)
> 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001:
> the second parameter - boolean true, padded to 32 bytes

The 68 bytes is the `calldata`: `0xcdcd77c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000450000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001`.

Comment: I'd like to leave a comment for those who, like me, were confused at first : the padded values could be  wrapped due to your screen resolution
the values are (as it was explained) therefore the concatenation of 
0xcdcd77c0 ,
0x00....0045 ,
0x00........01

Answer (score 18):

`calldata` is where data from external calls to functions is stored.

Functions can be called internally, e.g. from within the contract, or externally. When a function's visibility is `external`, only external contracts can call that function.

When such an external call happens, the data of that call is stored in `calldata`.

Read also here: [`external` vs `public` best practices](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19380/external-vs-public-best-practices)

Comment: External calls of functions! I nust know we can call a function but this terminology I dont det this

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit

Comment: I edited the response to include more info

Answer (score 5):

The `Calldata` is a read-only byte-addressable space where the data parameter of a transaction or call is held. Unlike the Stack, to use this data you have to specify an exact byte offset and number of bytes you want to read. The opcodes related to Calldata provided by EVM are:

> • CALLDATASIZE returns the size of transaction data
>
> • CALLDATALOAD imports 32 bytes of transaction data onto the stack
>
> • CALLDATACOPY copies transaction data of a certain number of bytes to
> memory

`calldata` behaves almost like `memory`. It is an unmodifiable and temporary area that can be used to store function arguments. As copying between memory and storage can be quite expensive, specifying a location can be
helpful to control the gas expenditure at times.