# Using an imported variable inside function modifier

Tags: solidity

I am trying to create a modifier that will cause a function to revert if a bool from an imported contract is = to true.

This is the modifier I am trying to make

```
  modifier notCompleted() {
    require(
      exampleExternalContract.completed = false
    );
    _;
  }
```

This is the imported function and variable.

```
bool public completed;

function complete() public payable {
    completed = true;
}
```

Solidity gives me the error: `Expression has to be an lvalue.`

Answer (score 0):

First, your code should be

```
  exampleExternalContract.completed == false // notice the double equal
```

Second,
please have a read here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/19391/45721

You should consider implementing a method and make it external

e.g

```
function whatIsComplete() external returns(bool) {
  return completed;
}
```

and in your modifier have

```
require(
  exampleExternalContract.whatIsComplete() == false
);
```